# Append all option text except first value

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to add text to the end of every option in a drop down except the first value `[option value="0"]` ?

```
<select name="DdlStockOptions" id="DdlStockOptions" class="stock-dropdown" _flx1_12_1="1" _flx1_13_1="1">
            <option value="0">Make Your Selection</option>
            <option value="127285">Pink</option>
            <option value="127286">Yellow </option>
            <option value="127287">Green </option>
            <option value="127288">Purple </option>
        </select>
```

I've used the following JS to append '- In Stock' to the end but it appears on every value including 'Make Your Selection' which I'm trying to avoid:

```
    $("#DdlStockOptions option").append('- In Stock');
```

Comment: maybe, if option value != 0{ $("#DdlStockOptions option").append('- In Stock');}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $("#DdlStockOptions :not(:first-child)").append('- In Stock');
```

This will select everything except the first child as requested. It is using pseudo classes to exclude the first child of your selector, thus leaving all other options without having to add anything in your html.

I would strongly advice you to disable the first option thought, to avoid other problems and make sure to server side validate your code as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would choose to mark the default option as `disabled` and `selected` (so it's selected by default) and then only append to elements that are not `disabled`, using the [`$(...).not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) function:

```js
$("#DdlStockOptions option").not("[disabled]").append(" - In Stock")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="DdlStockOptions" id="DdlStockOptions" class="stock-dropdown" _flx1_12_1="1" _flx1_13_1="1">
  <option value="0" disabled selected>Make Your Selection</option>
  <option value="127285">Pink</option>
  <option value="127286">Yellow </option>
  <option value="127287">Green </option>
  <option value="127288">Purple </option>
</select>
```

If you don't want the default option to be disabled, you can also just use `.not("[selected]")` here:

```js
$("#DdlStockOptions option").not("[selected]").append(" - In Stock")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="DdlStockOptions" id="DdlStockOptions" class="stock-dropdown" _flx1_12_1="1" _flx1_13_1="1">
  <option value="0" selected>Make Your Selection</option>
  <option value="127285">Pink</option>
  <option value="127286">Yellow </option>
  <option value="127287">Green </option>
  <option value="127288">Purple </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

without changing your html, you can cycle on all options that have a value other than 0 and add what you want

```js
  
  $("#DdlStockOptions option").each(function()
{
    if ($(this).val() != '0')
   { 
       $(this).append('- In Stock');
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="DdlStockOptions" id="DdlStockOptions"  class="stock-dropdown" _flx1_12_1="1" _flx1_13_1="1">
            <option value="0">Make Your Selection</option>
            <option value="127285">Pink</option>
            <option value="127286">Yellow </option>
            <option value="127287">Green </option>
            <option value="127288">Purple </option>
        </select>
```

**Demo:**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/gr3hb1us/9/)

Answer (score 0):

With native javascript you can use `document.querySelectorAll` and target all option except first one using `not` selector

```js
let x = document.querySelectorAll('#DdlStockOptions option:not([value="0"]');
x.forEach(function(item) {
  item.innerHTML = item.innerHTML + '- In Stock'
})
```

```html
<select name="DdlStockOptions" id="DdlStockOptions" class="stock-dropdown" _flx1_12_1="1" _flx1_13_1="1">
  <option value="0">Make Your Selection</option>
  <option value="127285">Pink</option>
  <option value="127286">Yellow </option>
  <option value="127287">Green </option>
  <option value="127288">Purple </option>
</select>
```